# Redis ordering a sorted set

Tags: sorting, redis, sortedset

I'm trying to sort user objects stored as hashes in Redis. 
The keys are like `users:valid:2`, `users:valid:5`, `users:valid:10`, `users:invalid:14`, etc.

My goal is to fetch users ordered by their ids ASC, valid users first.

I additionally store users ids in a sorted set where "score" is a filter id. Filters mapping is like `{ valid: 0, invalid: 1 }`

```
$redis.zadd 'sorted-ids', 0, 2
$redis.zadd 'sorted-ids', 0, 5
$redis.zadd 'sorted-ids', 0, 10
$redis.zadd 'sorted-ids', 1, 14
```

It lets to fetch user ids already being sorted ASC, valid first. Great! However...

```
$redis.zrange 'sorted-ids', 0, -1, with_scores: true
=> [["10", 0.0], ["2", 0.0], ["5", 0.0], ["14", 1.0]]
```

"10" comes before "2".
So the ids are not actually ASC-ordered because they're stored as strings.

https://redis.io/commands/zadd

> When multiple elements have the same score, they are ordered
>   lexicographically (they are still ordered by score as a first key,
>   however, locally, all the elements with the same score are relatively
>   ordered lexicographically). The lexicographic ordering used is binary,
>   it compares strings as array of bytes.

Is there a way to achieve this sorting properly in Redis? Like storing `ids` as integers to avoid lexographic ordering or any other way I can come up with?

Comment: Just pad your IDs with zeros, i.e. '1' becomes '000000001', and lexicographical ordering will work for you. Makes sure, however, that the length of padded IDs stays the same (e.g. 9 digits)

Comment: Haha, perfect, thanks Itamar! :D If you post it as answer I'll accept, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pad your IDs (Sorted Set members) with zeros, i.e. '1' becomes '000000001', and lexicographical ordering will work for you. Makes sure, however, that the length of padded IDs stays the same (e.g. 9 digits).